# Read with PubsubIO with custom coder

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I can read PubSub messages from a topic using PubsubIO as follows:

```java
pipeline.apply("read", PubsubIO.readMessages().fromTopic(options.getPubsubReadTopic()))
.apply( /* rest of the pipeline that works on PubSubMessage records */ )
```

The data inside the PubSub messages is wrapped in our custom wrappers, and is not easy to work with. I would like to create class CustomPubsubIO and use it in a similar manner:

```java
pipeline.apply("read", CustomPubsubIO.readTyped<MyType>().fromTopic(options.getPubsubReadTopic()))
.apply( /* rest of the pipeline that works on MyType records */ )
```

I was able to create a custom `CustomCoder<MyType>`, but I am having trouble creating `PubsubIO.Read<MyType>` with it. `PubsubIO.Read` is abstract in `PubsubIO`, and is used with `@AutoValue`, seems like I cannot extend it directly

What is the right way of creating a `Read<>` with custom coder?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any specific reason to create your custom type of `PubsubIO.Read`? Otherwise, you can just use `PubsubIO.readMessages()` and combine a `DoFn` to transform output `PubsubMessage` to whatever you want. The API supporting a custom coder and a custom parse function was [removed](https://github.com/apache/beam/commit/25dc94bc971a0cb8848777c48495929f6dbe8f69#diff-cfdca1a326496dabb9a075878204894fR715) two years ago since using a `DoFn` seems to be a clearer and semantically equivalent way of generating custom types.

Comment: Well the short answer is I am in charge of an infrastructure library that should simplify writing dataflow jobs that read automatically collected data (e.g. API call latencies). Giving them one line `ExtraPubsubIO.<String>read()` that produces a collection of Strings is more user-friendly than asking to run a `DoFn` with custom transform.
But the fact it was removed from the API makes me think about it again.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I was able to do it kinda. I had to put my `CustomPubsubIO` class in `package org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.pubsub` because `AutoValue_PubsubIO_Read` is package-protected. So I am not sure this solution will work in future (looks more like a hack)

Anyway, here is the simplified code:

```java
package org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.pubsub;

import org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.pubsub.PubsubIO.Read;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.SimpleFunction;

public class ExtraPubsubIO {

  public static <T> Read<T> read() {
    return new AutoValue_PubsubIO_Read.Builder<T>()
        .setPubsubClientFactory(PubsubJsonClient.FACTORY)
        .setCoder(new CustomTypeInPubSubCoder<>())
        .setParseFn(new CustomTypeUnwrapFn<>())
        .setNeedsAttributes(false)
        .build();
  }

  private static class CustomTypeUnwrapFn<T> extends SimpleFunction<PubsubMessage, T> {

    @Override
    public T apply(PubsubMessage input) {
      return CustomTypeUnwrapper.unwrap(input);
    }
  }
}
```

And then use it in the pipeline like this:

```java
pipeline.apply("Read PubSub messages", ExtraPubsubIO.<String>read().fromTopic(options.getPubsubReadTopic()))
        .apply("Write File(s)", TextIO.write()...
        .run()
```